# Fitting 2D data using locally weighted regression method (LOWESS) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit for the first time in Matlab, a two dimensional datapoints `[x, y]` (both `x` and `y` are 1D entries) using the locally weighed regression algorithm (LOWESS). I implemented the code snippet below which uses a noisy Gaussian curve and try to recover `[x, yfitted]` using the LOWESS method.

```
clearvars;
close all;
clc;

n = 10;
fit_frac = 0.2;
x = zeros(n, 1); x(1:end) = 1:n;
dx = 0.1;
x = x*dx;
xcenter = (n + 1)/2*dx;
x = x - xcenter;
% Gaussian initial signal
y = exp(-x.^2./sqrt(2));
% ad an offset of 1%;
y = y + 0.01.*max(y).*(rand(n, 1)*2 - 1);
%
datain = [x, y];
argfrac = fit_frac.*ones(n, 1);
% f = fit(data(cid).w_store.', data(cid).p_store.', 'lowess');
f = fit(datain, argfrac, 'lowess');
```

Nevertheless, when I

```
 figure; plot(f);
```

draw a 3D plot instead of a 2D plot of the fitted data which in my best scenario will recover the original Gaussian distribution.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax, `fit([x,y],z,...)` fits a surface. And the `lowess` model is only supported for fitting surfaces (as per the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcxyx-1)). So, you will have a fitted surface in `f`.

You want to fit a Gaussian, so you should use the `gauss1` model for fitting:

```matlab
f = fit(x, y, 'gauss1');
plot(f, x, y)
```

Comment: Good point! I was using a similar algorithm in FORTRAN for curve fitting and directly assumed the same goes for the Matlab routine. Many thanks. In fact the Gaussian model perfectly do the job.